# laravel using scope method

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I'm trying to learn laravel scoping, I created my first scope but im getting this error message npw

ErrorException in Support.php line 26:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$User

And this is the line

```
public static function getTicket($id)
{
    $ticket = Support::where('id', $id)->User::owner(Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return $ticket;
}
```

and this is in user model

```
public function scopeOwner($query, $flag)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $flag);
}
```

Relation between user and support

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Can you please explain to me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: My first guess would be: Support::where('id', $id)->user->owner(Auth::user()->id)->first(); But Support model must have relation with User model for this.

Comment: It does but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: How about Support::where('id', $id)->user()->owner(Auth::user()->id)->first(); ?

Comment: now im getting this BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()

Comment: Could you show how you defined relation between Support and User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "User::" like this :

```
public static function getTicket($id)
{
    $ticket = Support::where('id', $id)->owner(Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return $ticket;
}
```

then move  function scopeOwner  from user model to Support model .

Comment: Well it's working now but, should i be defining scopes in the same model im calling them from ?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the scope wrong. The scope should be in the model on which you wish to use it. So move it to `Support` model.

```
public function scopeOwner($query, $id)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $id);
}

public static function getTicket($id)
{
    $ticket = Support::where('id', $id)->owner(Auth::user()->id)->first();

    return $ticket;
}
```

You can also do this

```
public static function getTicket($id)
{
    $ticket = static::where('id', $id)->owner(auth()->id())->first();

    return $ticket;
}
```